# Get array of joined values from Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google sheet I have objects (rows) which are unambiguously identifiable by combination of two of their values `id` and `date` stored in non adjacent columns. Now I need to check if a certain object of this type exist within this sheet and if so in which row. I'd like to have an array like `object[<index = row no>][<id>+<delimiter>+<date>]` that allows me to find and locate one of them by this:

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890').getSheetByName('Entries List');
objectsIds = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 100).getDisplayValues();    // with 5 = column containing ids
objectsDates = sheet.getRange(1, 11, 100).getDisplayValues(); // with 11 = column containing dates

// Create array of objects with joint/combined value of id+#+date:
//                                 <-------ID---------->#<--date-->
consloe.log(objects[0]); // writes e. g. "4e6aa8-8f709d-a208b38#2022-02-19" which is unambiguously identifiable

sampleIdDate = sampleId + "#" + sampleDate;
rowOfFirstOccurance = objects.findIndex(e => === sampleIdDate);
```

Actually the delimiter can be omitted. What is the best way to create this array of combined values in one attribute/field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890').getSheetByName('Entries List');
var objectsIds = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 100).getDisplayValues();    // with 5 = column containing ids
var objectsDates = sheet.getRange(1, 11, 100).getDisplayValues(); // with 11 = column containing dates

var objects = objectsIds.map(([v], i) => `${v}#${objectsDates[i][0]}`); // Added

// Create array of objects with joint/combined value of id+#+date:
//                                 <-------ID---------->#<--date-->
console.log(objects[0]); // writes e. g. "4e6aa8-8f709d-a208b38#2022-02-19" which is unambiguously identifiable
var sampleIdDate = sampleId + "#" + sampleDate;
var rowOfFirstOccurance = objects.findIndex(e => e === sampleIdDate); // Modified
```

- In your script, please modify `consloe.log(objects[0]);` to `console.log(objects[0]);`.
- From `Actually the delimiter can be omitted.`, if you want to remove the delimiter, please modify `var objects = objectsIds.map(([v], i) =>` ${v}#${objectsDates[i][0]}`);` to `var objects = objectsIds.map(([v], i) =>` ${v}${objectsDates[i][0]}`);`.

#### Note:

- As additional information, for example, in your script, you are using 2 `getDisplayValues()` methods. I think that this can be reduced to one time as follows. By this, the process cost can be reduced a little.

  - From

    ```
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890').getSheetByName('Entries List');
      var objectsIds = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 100).getDisplayValues();    // with 5 = column containing ids
      var objectsDates = sheet.getRange(1, 11, 100).getDisplayValues(); // with 11 = column containing dates

      var objects = objectsIds.map(([v], i) => `${v}#${objectsDates[i][0]}`); // Added
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890').getSheetByName('Entries List');
      var values = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 100, 7).getDisplayValues();
      var objects = values.map(r => `${r[0]}#${r[6]}`);
    ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)